# Can I disable / edit the automatic jump-to-top scroll when tapping status bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, scrolltop

I'm using an app with a tableView that auto-scrolls downward, so tapping the status bar, which would normally jump to the top of the table, causes problems (it begins scrolling but if the auto-scroll ticks, it stops and leaves it somewhere in the middle).

I'd either like to disable it, or at least have shove some code in when it's tapped to temporarily pause the timer and then resume it when it reaches the top.

Are there any means of achieving either of these things?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`UIScrollView` (and `UITableView` as a subclass of it) has `scrollsToTop` property which defaults to `YES`, making it scroll to top when status bar is tapped. All you have to do is set it to `NO`.

However, please keep in mind that iOS users might expect this behavior, so turning it off may not be the best idea from user experience standpoint. You can also leave it as `YES` and return `NO` from `-scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:` delegate method if you only need it disabled at specific times.

Actually, handling it via delegate might be a perfect fit for your case:

```
- (BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // disable timer
    return YES;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // re-enable timer
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try:

```
[myView setScrollsToTop:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

For swift 5

func scrollViewShouldScrollToTop(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) -> Bool {
return false
}

Comment: It doesn't override any method, because it's a delegate, not class method. Please correct the answer, from other stand-points it's working since .scrollsToTop property of table view isn't working anymore (iOS 15.4)